# java script can't change the content of a label

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with this script?
I'm trying to make the text in the label the same as the button clicked.

### if a + button is clicked, the label will have + written in it.

```
<form name="frm">
    <button name="plus">+</button>
    <label id="operator"></label>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function operatorClick () {
            var a=event.target;
            switch (a)
           {
                case +
                    frm.operator.innerHTML='+';
           ...
```

a red squiggly line appears under the = in the last line. I tried with/out the'', I tried frm.event...
please help.

Comment: Syntax error. `case +` is invalid.

Comment: What is the intention of `case +`? `case` must elect on the DOM object `a`

Comment: Don't rely on the global event object, it won't work in Firefox, and don't rely on ID's being global, use getElementById instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function operatorClick () {
    var a=event.target;
    switch (a.innerHtml)
   {
        case "+":
            frm.operator.innerHTML='+';
            break;
   }
}
```

Your code just had so many errors. Syntax errors, such as missing quotes around the '+', missing a colon after the case; missing a `break` statement. You also were trying to compare a DOM element instead of its HTML content.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is switch on the clicked button's `innerText` property. That change, and a correction to the way the `case` statement was set up, are illustrated below.

```
    <form name="frm">
    <button name="plus">+</button>
    <label id="operator"></label>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function operatorClick () {
            var a=event.target;
            switch (a.innerText)
            {
                case "+":
                    frm.operator.innerHTML='+';
                    break;
            ...
```